# Let $A$ be a subset of $C$ and $B$ a proper subgroup of $C$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $B$ a proper subgroup of $C$. Show that there exists a subset $A$ of $C$ such that $C = \langle A \rangle$ and  $A \cap B = \varnothing$.

I am not sure how to start with this one.

Comment: This is not true.  Since $A$ and $B$ are subgroups of $B$, $A \cap B$ needs not be empty (unless $A$ does not form a group.).

Comment: I have edit the question

Comment: I would show that any group is not the union of two proper subgroups.

Comment: i can show any group is not the union of two proper subgroups, but I still didn't get the idea here

Comment: I'd start with $A = C \setminus B$ (which is overkill).  Rephrasing, Paul Plummer, can $A$ be a subgroup of $C$?

Comment: Certainly $\langle C \setminus B \rangle \cup B = C$.

Comment: @user132177, have you studied already Zorn's Lemma?

Comment: @DonAntonio no, i haven't

Comment: @DonAntonio I am curious as to what you were planning (finding a minimal $A$?)

Comment: @PaulPlummer, I was thinking of taking *maximal* such $\;A\;$ using Z.L., but trying to wor out the proof I get stuck. BTW, I also don't get the hint in the answer below...

Comment: @DonAntonio Okay, I was thinking you were going to do some something with reverse inclusion ($A \leq B$ iff $B \subseteq A$) and see if, with the help of Zorn's lemma get a much smaller set than $C \setminus B$ (which would be maximal with the subset relation). As for the hint $Bc$ and $c^{-1}B$ are disjoint from $B$. The idea would be to pick a $ b \in B $ and an element from $Bc$ and one from $ c^{-1}B $ that multiply to get $b$.

Answer (score 4):

The stipulations $A\subseteq C$ and $A\cap B=\varnothing$ tell us that $A\subseteq C\setminus B$. The stipulation $\langle A\rangle=C$ tells us that $A$ has to be "big enough" (enough to generate all of $C$). Might as well pick $A=C\setminus B$.

To show $\langle C\setminus B\rangle=C$ it suffices to show $B\subseteq\langle C\setminus B\rangle$. Can you show this?

Hint: the elements of $C\setminus B$ are all in some left or right coset of $B$. To obtain $b\in B$, pick some element $c\in C\setminus B$ and consider elements of $Bc$ and $c^{-1}B$ to do the job..

Comment: is that Bc and c^-1B are both in <C\B> and Bc*c^-1B = B^2 = B so B is also in <C\B>

Comment: @user132177 Right.